# Geometric intuition of a point in a flag manifold

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, visualization

From Wikipedia

> According to basic results of linear algebra, any two complete flags in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ are no different from each other from a geometric point of view. That is to say, the general linear group acts transitively on the set of all complete flags.

So I understad that **a point in a flag manifold $X_{1}\subset X_{2}\subset ...\subset X_{n} = X$ is a $n$-hyperplane** regardless some subspace $V_{i},i<n$ is missing in the sequence.

1-Is this correct?

2-If so; is there a generalization of the flag manifold in the sense that a point in the manifold (or a more general space) represents something geometrically more complicated/general than an $n$-hyperplane?

**EDIT: In response to the answer of @Nicolas Hemelsoet**

I do not see the thing clearly . I am trying to visualize the point in a flag manifold apart from  knowing what the definition of the flag is.

Let´s see  the last parapgraph of this article https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/grassmannians-and-flag-varieties/ I understand that there is not something like a (spatial) "flag" in some space but a collection of {a point, a line, a plane, a $3$-plane... a $k$-plane} in different subspaces (one of each is contained in the following one). But the data that maps for example the line in $V_{1}$ with the plane in $V_{2}$ are not part of the specification  of the (flag) manifold?

Comment: No. A point in the flag manifold is a flag, that is a sequence $V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \dot \subset V_{n-1} \subset V_n$ with $\dim V_i = i$. A point in the Grassmanian $G(k,n)$ is a $k$-plane. A point in $G(n,n+1)$ is a $n$-hyperplane.

Comment: To answer your second question, there are generalization of flag manifolds, in many different ways.  You might want to google moduli spaces.  This can get extremely complicated, fair warning, but also super powerful.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I have updated the question in response to your answer. Take a look of it if you  have time. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chequez : I still don't really understand, what is the "data that maps the line in $V_1$ with the plane in $V_2$ " ?

Comment: @Callus As far as I know I dont think that moduli spaces are generalizations of flag spaces in any sense. From nlab "There are quantum, noncommutative and infinite-dimensional generalizations" but I cannot find clear information about this. Could you explain what you meant further?

Comment: I'll do my best in a comment.  This is almost exactly what a moduli space is: a space whose points represent sub-geometric objects of another space.  Some examples are Hilbert spaces ( subvarieties with the same hilbert polynomial ), the moduli stack of elliptic curves, moduli spaces of stable maps, Kontsevich moduli space, etc.  None of these are super easy to understand, and indeed there's a theorem that hilbert schemes are as bad as possible.  There are some simpler and more classical examples that you could look at, like the generalized flag varieties ( wikipedia helps here ).